# How to show content and ask to download a file on the same page?

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, download

In my application, Clicking on button a pop up window appear.
I want to show some contents on the popup along with i want to ask the user to download a file?
Is it possible? If yes what content type should i set the content type in header?

Comment: I don't think so.  You might have to make your question to the user a button or hyperlink.

Comment: Why do you want one button to do two things? Just use two buttons (or links) and _let the user decide_ if they want to view the content, download the file, or both.

Comment: If the user selected both, the problem in the question still exists.